# Making my site show up in news aggregators

Tags: rss, aggregators

I keep running into posts about *creating* a news aggregator, but how do I make my site (a blog/news site) compatible with one? My office received an email about making our site "Feedly-friendly," but I'm trying to figure out if there is a generic way of making it work across many different aggregators (Google News, etc..) Is it just RSS? Do people even still use RSS for this stuff? I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's RSS... and yes, RSS is the way to go. It's the only format that is both consumed by a lot of different readers: Google News, Flipboard, Feedly, Newsblur... and hundreds of others, as well as published by pretty much any kind of website.

Now, based on your CMS, it's very likely that there are already RSS feeds generated either "natively" or using a plugin.

Comment: Much appreciated. We have no CMS, everything was coded by my boss personally, many many years ago, although he never took the time to actually implement RSS, even though it was getting really popular by then.